# How do you keep the UIImageView "full screen" on iPhone while scrolling up/down the uiscrollview

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Basically what I am trying to do is keep a "full screen" sized image view that I have in a scroll view on the iphone stay like that while the user is scrolling.

for example:

I set the image view to the size of the iphone using bounds
so lets say the height of the imageview/iphone screen is 300.
but the height/length of the scroll view is 1000.
obviously when the user scrolls down it passes the bottom of the image and now the image is no longer the background.

how do I move the imageview to keep up with the user scrolling so that it shows as a still background in thier eyes?

Comment: Why not just make the scrollview transparent and set an image view behind it?

Comment: lol that makes perfect sence lol. looks like I was thinking too much into it. That would give eactly the outcome I'm looking for. Thanks. put that as an answer so I can select it and give it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just make the scrollview transparent and set an image view behind it?